# HTTPS with NodeJS swagger-express-mw npm package

Tags: node.js, express, https, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger-express-mw NPM package for creating REST services, when I run the project with "swagger project start" then it publishes the APIs over HTTP, how can I use HTTPS instead.

I have used HTTPS using vanilla npm packages as below:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var app = require('express')();
var options = {
   key  : fs.readFileSync('my.private.key'),
   cert : fs.readFileSync('my.certificate.cer')
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Yuhooo! Response over HTTPS!!! ');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8443, function () {
   console.log('Server started @ 8443!');
});
```

But I am not sure how to achieve the same with swagger-express-mw, Below is the code snippet from my app.js which starts the listener. Not getting any option to use HTTPS as the protocol here

```
SwaggerExpress.create(configuration, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);
  var port = config.get('server.port') || process.env.PORT || 8080;
    app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at port %d', port);
});

var swaggerDoc = jsYaml.load(fs.readFileSync('./api/swagger/swagger.yaml'));
// Initialize the Swagger middleware for the api doc purpose
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
  // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`app.listen` is simply a shortcut you can use

```
SwaggerExpress.create(configuration, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);
  var port = process.env.PORT || 443;
    https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Server started @ %s!', port);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swagger 2.0 spec with middleware your swagger configuration file can be set to only accept certain schemes:

```
# Schemes is statically set here but will be overridden in app.js with 
swagger object
schemes:
   - https
```

You can review the specification and go to Fixed Fields: http://swagger.io/specification/